# Matrix condition not outputting result C++

Tags: c++, matrix

For every column that contains the minimum number of the whole matrix, I want to replace the column entirely with the minimum number.

e.g:

```
input
8 3 3 7         
2 1 6 1             
8 1 3 1             
9 1 7 1         

///////

output
8 1 3 1 
2 1 6 1 
8 1 3 1 
9 1 7 1
```

I came up with this idea:

```
step 1: find minimum
step 2: create a bool variable and make it false (so active=false)
step 3: go through every column and check if it has the minimum number, if it does -> restart the loop 
and make the bool variable true (so active=true). If active==true, replace the column with the minimum number
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
int main(){
    int i, j, n=4, m=4, v[101][101];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            cin>>v[i][j];
        }
    }
    int minv=1000000000;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            if(v[i][j]<minv){
                minv=v[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    bool active=false;
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(v[i][j]==minv){
                i=0;
                active=true;
            }
            if(active){
                v[i][j]=minv;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
            cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the compiler doesn't output anything. I assume it's the

```
for(j=0; j<m; j++){
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(v[i][j]==minv){
                i=0;
                active=true;
            }
            if(active){
                v[i][j]=minv;
            }
        }
    }
```

Piece of code. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: You keep resetting i to 0. Infinite loop probably.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code ? especially in the loop where you set/unset `bool active`

Comment: What do you mean "the compiler doesn't output anything"? A successful compiler run _won't_ output anything to the screen, if that's what you mean, or do you mean there is no output file _and_ no terminal output (or are you using a GUI)? Let's start with what compiler and environment are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked about the solution in C++. You tend to use static arrays that are more C practice. I took freedom and rewrite your code to a solution that is more of C++ nature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = {
        {8, 3, 3, 7},
        {2, 1, 6, 1},
        {8, 1, 3, 1},
        {9, 1, 7, 1}};
    std::vector<int> min_row;
    int minv = v[0][0];
    //Here we find min value of matrix
    for (auto i : v)
        for (auto j : i)
            if (j < minv)
                minv = j;
    //Here we find columns that hold min value
    for (auto i : v)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i.size(); j++)
            if (i.at(j) == minv)
                min_row.push_back(j);
    //After looping trough columns that has
    //min values we change all values to min
    for (auto j : min_row)
        //Notice here we used reference so we could actually change the value
        for (auto &i : v)
            i.at(j) = minv;
    //Here we just print out our matrix
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        for (auto j : i)
            std::cout << j << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems first is setting active to false outside the loop which will result on infinite loop and the whole matrix will be set to minv.
The second is this condition:

```
if(v[i][j]==minv){
     i=0;
     active=true;
}
```

will always return you back to index 0 since every time you find the minv in the inner loop will be infinite, so it should be instead :

```
if(v[i][j]==minv && !active){
     i=0;
     active=true;
}
```

at the end that loop should look like this:

```
for(j=0; j<m; j++){
        bool active=false;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(v[i][j]==minv && !active){
                i=0;
                active=true;
            }
            if(active){
                v[i][j]=minv;
            }
        }
    }
```